# how to getList of entity Type using Where Clause

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

In my case i want list of enity type where particular id match.

Here's my code can any one tell me correct the code how can achieve this any one can write proper code how can i acheive.

**here my code**

```
public static List<Institute> GetInstitutions(long OrgID)
{
    using (SchoolGapEntities1 Db = new SchoolGapEntities1())
    {
         if (Db.Institutes.Any(I => I.INS_FK_ORGID == OrgID))
         {
             return Db.Set<Institute>().Where(I => I.INS_FK_ORGID == OrgID).ToList();
         }
    }
    // return Db.Set<Institute>().Where(I => I.INS_FK_ORGID == OrgID).ToList();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use `Where` method with your expression:

```
public static List<Institute> GetInstitutions(long OrgID)
{
    using (SchoolGapEntities1 Db = new SchoolGapEntities1())
    {
        return Db.Institutes.Where(I => I.INS_FK_ORGID == OrgID).ToList();
    }
}
```

Comment: if i using return inside getting error must return, because scope issue.

Comment: Sorry, i don't understand what you mean.